# Pagination in http request get by id

Tags: c#, http, pagination, backend, api-design

I want to implement pagination on an api call that returns a list of strings, based on the id and I am having a little trouble here. Here is my HttpGet call

```
        [Route("getLogsFileNames/{id}")]
        public IActionResult GetLogsFileNames(Guid id, string include = "")
        {
            return Ok(_deidentificationService.GetLogsFileNames(id, include));
        }
```

And here is the implementation from the service

```
public List<string> GetLogsFileNames(Guid deviceId, string include = "")
        {
            var blobNames = new List<string>();
            var blobs = _blobUtils.GetBlobsFromContainer(deviceId);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(include))
            {
                blobs.ToList().ForEach(blob => blobNames.Add(blob.Name));
            }
            else
            {
                blobs.Where(blob => blob.Name.ToLower().Contains(include.ToLower())).ToList()
                     .ForEach(blob => blobNames.Add(blob.Name));
            }

            return blobNames;
        }
```

any ideas?

Comment: Side notes: `ToList().ForEach(` why `ToList`? Also `blob.Name.ToLower().Contains(include.ToLower())` is much better if you do `blob.Name.IndexOf(include, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a `PageNumber` to your service. You also need to define a `PageSize`. Then you can implement a selection of a subset of your list:

```
blobNames.Skip((PageNumber-1)*PageSize).Take(PageSize);
```